# Strange Error regarding using Std::List as a Class Member Variable

Tags: c++, std, stdlist

I am trying to implement an event handling system in C++ and encountered a compiler error for std::list which I am not able to figure out why.

There is an EventManager class whose role is to manage and fire events. There is a list which stores events to be processed.

If the std::list is declared as a class member, there is an error. Whereas if the list is declared as a local method variable, there is no error.

The class goes like this:

```
class EventManager
{
   //Queue for events. IEventPtr is a typedef of shared_ptr to an 
   //Events class
   typedef std::list<IEventPtr> EventQueue; 
   EventQueue m_eventQueue;

   virtual bool VQueueEvent(const IEventPtr& pEvent) const;
}
```

The definition for the VQueueEvent method is:

```
bool EventManager::VQueueEvent(const IEventPtr& pEvent) const 
{
    //compiler highlighted an error for a class member list
    m_eventQueue.push_back(pEvent);

    //a locally declared list works. No compiler error
    std::list<IEventPtr> eventList;
    eventList.push_back(pEvent);

    return true;
}
```

From the above code, the compiler underlined the dot notation and had the message "No instance of overloaded function std::list<.....> matches the argument list and object (the object has type qualifiers that prevent a match. Argument types are (const IEventPtr). Object type is const EventManager::EventQueue"

When compiling, the compiler will show the error:

std::list<....>::push_back. 2 overloads have no legal conversion for 'this' pointer

What is causing this error and how to solve it?

Comment: You can't modify data members in a `const` member function.

Comment: Thank you. I removed the const and the compiler error went away. Does  this mean that const methods cannot add or remove items from data structures which are class members?

Comment: Yes that's what `const` means, it guarantees that the member function won't modify data members. If it has to modify then it shouldn't be `const`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method **EventManager::VQueueEvent** is marked **const**. This means it can't modify class members.

However, the push_back method clearly needs to modify the content of the eventList member, and thus, the error.

Remove the const qualifier and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You wasn't able to `push_back` to a class member beacause you declared the member function as `const` which means you can't modify the class and any of its members.

The definition for the `VQueueEvent` method should be like this:

```
bool EventManager::VQueueEvent(const IEventPtr& pEvent) /* const */
{
    // Now this should work fine
    m_eventQueue.push_back(pEvent);

    return true;
}
```

and declaration like this:

```
virtual bool VQueueEvent(const IEventPtr& pEvent) /* const */;
```